# Auto start of a Service of a System app in Android

Tags: android, service, android-service, system, autostart

I want to initiate a system app service without opening the service app even once. It should run once its installed. I know how to add a boot receiver and restart the service on reboot of the phone. I would like to know how to make the service start when the application is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, your user will have to open the App at least once to initiate any code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this,this is a Rogue software behavior , after android 4.0, If your application has never been started, even BroadcastReceiver can't work, user must start it at least once

Answer (score 0):

you have to create one activity file. And when you run first time the application Android os will provide the PID. And Android os only send broadcast to who have the PID. To run service without interface you have to give any broadcast. For example boot completion. But order to get broadcast from os you need PID. And for PID you have to lunch your application at list once with activity class.